# "to the east" without "of something"

Tags: american-english, prepositional-phrases

I'm learning the points of the compass, and the prepositions in, on, to.

My book has one sentence

**Cars can park between the Community Hall and that line of trees to the east.**

So where exactly is the parking lot?

[image]

Is the line of trees to the east of the hall?

Or is the parking between the hall and the east of tree?

[image]

Or we first find the middle point between the hall and the trees, then to the east?

[image]

Comment: Cars can park between the Community Hall and that line of trees **to the east of the Community Hall**. From west to east: Community hall - parking - line of trees.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey like it always refers to the nearest noun? Can you say anything more? I'm still a bit confused.

Comment: In your second and third diagrams, the car park is not _between the Hall and the trees_.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @Kate Bunting:

> In your second and third diagrams, the car park is *not* between the Hall and the trees.

From a more general point of view, we can perhaps come up with three scenarios:

1. The Plausible
2. The Less-plausible
3. The Come-on-that's-ridiculous

**1. The Plausible:**

As depicted in your first diagram, "to the east" refers to the trees, the immediately preceding noun:

The trees are to the east.
To the east of what?
To the east of the hall, the obvious candidate for the point of reference.

**2. The Less-plausible:**

"To the east" can also be considered from *the observer*'s point of view:

The trees are to the east. 
To the east of what/who?
To the east of the Observer.

The observer may, for example, have the hall to his/her north and the trees to his/her east:

[image: Image.]

**3. The Come-on-that's-ridiculous**

You could (try and) argue that "to the east" can also refer to the verb "park", but then it should have been written as follows, shouldn't it?

*Cars can park **to the east** between the Community Hall and that line of trees.*

In this interpretation, the hall and the trees are both to the east of the speaker/observer (in any different number of arrangements) and the car park is between them.

It would take an immensely sloppy writer/speaker/thinker to botch things up that much... but then again as we all know human stupidity is boundless, so why not!

Comment: What good second and third points! How would you express my third diagram that we first find the middle point between the hall and the trees, then to the east?